# SuiteCRM PDF Template Not Rendering Variables

Tags: parsing, variables, pdf, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I'm using SuiteCRM 7.4. and here's my problem:

I added two custom fields, "Loading Port" (`loading_port_c`) & "Price Terms" (`price_list_c`).

1. Created a PDF Template, and inserted field:

   [image]
2. Quotes->Print to PDF, and here's what happened:

   [image]

The loading port doesn't get parsed! Any ideas? Am I missing something? Thank you.

Comment: Its ugrent, any guidence?

Comment: You need to debug for actual issue behind it. Just trace error using the modules/PDfTemplatemoduledir/generatePdf.php file.